# My iPhone app keeps crashing when I click RUN in Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I get this from the Console from the iPhone

```
May 29 13:26:01 iPhone-5S securityd[550] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [securityd] (793.00)
��May 29 13:26:01 iPhone-5S securityd[550] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/rwxlib.dylib
��May 29 13:26:01 iPhone-5S securityd[550] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/xCon.dylib
��May 29 13:26:02 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[555] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:02 iPhone-5S installd[44] <Error>: 0x2d5000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Emergency Closing.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
��May 29 13:26:02 iPhone-5S installd[44] <Error>: 0x2d5000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S installd[44] <Error>: May 29 13:26:03  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S SpringBoard[137] <Warning>: Killing com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing for termination assertion
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S lsd[173] <Warning>: updating identifier store
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S lsd[173] <Warning>: Attempting to store identifiers file
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S installd[44] <Error>: 0x2d5000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.41s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.19s; LS Sync: 0.12s; Overall: 0.72s
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[558] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[557] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
��May 29 13:26:03 iPhone-5S syncdefaultsd[557] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.apple.syncdefaultsd [syncdefaultsd] (793.00)
��May 29 13:26:04 iPhone-5S syncdefaultsd[557] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/rwxlib.dylib
��May 29 13:26:04 iPhone-5S syncdefaultsd[557] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/xCon.dylib
��May 29 13:26:05 iPhone-5S installd[44] <Error>: 0x45b000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1c55bb40 [0x3b86a0f0]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3b8569e4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1d850720 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3b857a34 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1d831c50 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3b854784 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3b856554 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3b857214 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1d837990 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3b853ea4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3b85be74 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3b85bea4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3b8592f4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1d8468d0 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1d838c30 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3b857e44 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3b85abe4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3b85bc74 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1d84c470 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S installd[44] <Error>: 0x2d5000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1d83bfa0 [0x3b86a0f0]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3b8569e4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1d8468d0 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3b857a34 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1d84e660 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3b854784 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3b856554 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3b857214 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1d833e90 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3b853ea4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3b85be74 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3b85bea4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3b8592f4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1d854a20 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1d84ca00 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3b857e44 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3b85abe4 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3b85bc74 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1d850720 [0x3b86a0f0]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[561] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[562] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[552] Builtin profile: debugserver (sandbox)
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S com.apple.debugserver-199[563] <Warning>: debugserver-199 for armv7.
May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S com.apple.debugserver-199[563] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S com.apple.debugserver-199[563] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing[0x8048][565]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing[0x8048]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[564] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[566] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[567] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[565] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[565] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/A503EED4-6A31-41A5-94BF-5ADA26723AE0 (sandbox)
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S com.apple.debugserver-199[563] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for debugger instructions.
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[568] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:06 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[569] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[570] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[571] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[572] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[573] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[574] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[575] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[576] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[577] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[578] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[579] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[580] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[581] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:07 iPhone-5S mobile_house_arrest[582] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S Emergency Closing[565] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing [Emergency Closing] (793.00)
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S Emergency Closing[565] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/3GMy3G.dylib
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S Emergency Closing[565] <Warning>: My3G Initializing in com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing  v5.0..
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S Emergency Closing[565] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlockerNetworks.dylib
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S Emergency Closing[565] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Nitrous.dylib
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S Emergency Closing[565] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S Emergency Closing[565] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/rwxlib.dylib
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing[0x8048][565]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing[0x8048]) Exited with code: 45
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing[0x8048]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing[0x8048]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483645 seconds
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S com.apple.debugserver-199[563] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [0233/1303]: error: ::read ( 5, 0x1c09fc, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
��May 29 13:26:08 iPhone-5S backboardd[64] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.oneorangetree.emergency-closing[0x8048]' exited abnormally with exit status 45
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.apple.AssistantServices [assistantd] (793.00)
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/3GMy3G.dylib
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Warning>: My3G Initializing in com.apple.AssistantServices  v5.0..
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlockerNetworks.dylib
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Nitrous.dylib
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/rwxlib.dylib
��May 29 13:26:13 iPhone-5S assistantd[584] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/xCon.dylib
��
```

I tried cleaning the target and I do not have an entitlement.plist
I do have an Info.plist for the app but it doesn't look out of the ordinary because its the stock one that is generated by Apple's Xcode.

I am running iOS 6.1.2 on my iPhone 5 with T-Mobile

Comment: Try looking here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127796/running-app-on-iphone4-from-xcode-fails

Comment: I did look at that first. It was unable to resolve the issue because the Mac I am using has NEVER had been used for development before. I installed all the provisioning profiles. The app is created on the iPhone 5 but I can't debug. The simulator works perfectly too

Comment: can anyone help with this?

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple radar://12053064 but would really like to fix my computer, iPhone or development environment

Answer (score 1):

I see you have xCon installed on your device, of which I am the developer. I found this post because I was just getting this same error, and it happens to be because of xCon. (Small world, isn't it?)

It's not really an issue I'm inclined to fix. Just put your phone into safe mode when you need to attach LLDB to an app you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up erasing the entire Hard Drive and starting over.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using "fopen" or "NSFileHandle"..etc to create file handles but you are not closing them appropriately (eg if you are using FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode ) then you should close file using fclose ( FILE * stream ))".Only max 78 files can be opened simultaneously in iPhone.