# mobile_house_arrest[xxx] <Error>: Max open files: 78

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm using `UIWebView` as a wrapper around my html5 application. Application implements a lot of video streaming - and is medium size (JS code).

When I actively use it I receive a lot of errors:

```
Jul 31 13:21:34 iPad mobile_house_arrest[483] <Error>: Max open files: 78

Jul 31 13:21:34 iPad mobile_house_arrest[485] <Error>: Max open files: 78

...

Jul 31 13:21:35 iPad mobile_house_arrest[505] <Error>: Max open files: 78
```

in the device's console - and it stops to respond. Meantime it works great in Safari browser on the same device.

Is there any known memory leak issue or better workaround that I can apply?

Comment: Same log when downloading a lot of data.

Comment: The "mobile_house_arrest" issue is discused here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127796/running-app-on-iphone4-from-xcode-fails

Answer (score 0):

You might be using "fopen" or "NSFileHandle"..etc to create file handles but you are not closing them appropriately (eg if you are using `FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode )` then you should close file using `fclose ( FILE * stream )`)".Only max 78 files can be opened simultaneously in iPhone device.