# Maximum amount of open files on iOS

Tags: ios, file-io

How many files can we safely keep open in an iOS application?

We are using FMOD to play audio in our game and apparently there a good strategy is to keep audio files pre-opened, but not loaded to memory, for rapid playback upon need.

I did not find information about either per-process limits not global system wide limits in Apple's documentation, here on SO, or anywhere else.

This quick test using a handy Python env on iPad suggests that the per-process limit is 250:

[image]

I think we stay below that limit. But we suspect that there is a rare problem situation where opening files fails.

Is there also a system wide limit that can affect at some point?

The per-app limit that I think I discovered with that test was asked in a comment in a related question but I can not comment there due to not having any reputation (first post): [on iOS/iPhone: "Too many open files": need to list open files (like lsof)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083608/on-ios-iphone-too-many-open-files-need-to-list-open-files-like-lsof/)

**EDIT:**

The limits are easy to check on OSX like this. Perhaps possible also on a jailbroken iOS device, or somehow from an app using Apple's API / launching that system command?

```
Tonis-MacBook-Pro:MacOS antont$ sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240
Tonis-MacBook-Pro:MacOS antont$ sysctl kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 12288
```

Comment: I can support your claim on an iPad Air iOS 9.2. After **250** calls to `[(NSData *) writeToFile:options:error:]`, I get the following stuffed into my error object's `debugDescription`: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "(null)" UserInfo={NSFilePath=..., NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x15d6c47f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=24 "Too many open files"}}`

Comment: Can you please help to retrieve how to find how many files open in iPad @ardnew? Thanks

Comment: How many in general or in your process? This question and answer are per process.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to get an error saying:

> Oct  7 15:24:08 iPhone-5 mobile_house_arrest[4354] : Max open
>   files: 78

This stack overflow thread is also mentioning 78 as the number:
[mobile_house_arrest[xxx] <Error>: Max open files: 78](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968425/mobile-house-arrestxxx-error-max-open-files-78)

hence, it's possible that 78 is the number, however I don't have any 'official' source to confirm, as Apple docs for example.

[Maximum amount of open files on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666921/maximum-amount-of-open-files-on-ios)