# IOS application works on the simulator but not on the device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I made a simple sign up application with parse backend. Everything works fine. I have no warnings or error code and I can also see the user in the parse dashboard when i create it. But the application only works at the simulator. When I put it on the device, it starts the application but shows a black screen. I tried with an another sample project, just to make sure that my code signing is valid and the other app works on device just fine. So i checked the console logs but I did not understand a whole lot. So could someone be able to help me with this? Thank you.

Here is the console log

```
Aug 30 18:16:13 Bla-Bla mobile_house_arrest[1179] <Error>: Max open files: 125
��Aug 30 18:16:15 Bla-Bla installd[54] <Error>: 0x2fe93000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Blast.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
��Aug 30 18:16:15 Bla-Bla installd[54] <Error>: 0x2fe93000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.BlaBla.Blast
��Aug 30 18:16:15 Bla-Bla installd[54] <Error>: Aug 30 18:16:15  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
��Aug 30 18:16:16 Bla-Bla SpringBoard[66] <Warning>: Killing com.BlaBla.Blast for termination assertion
��Aug 30 18:16:16 Bla-Bla lsd[89] <Warning>: updating identifier store
��Aug 30 18:16:16 Bla-Bla kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1182] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
��Aug 30 18:16:16 Bla-Bla installd[54] <Error>: 0x2fe93000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.22s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.75s; LS Sync: 0.32s; Overall: 1.55s
��Aug 30 18:16:16 Bla-Bla lsd[89] <Warning>: Attempting to store identifiers file
��Aug 30 18:16:23 Bla-Bla CommCenter[37] <Error>: kDataAttachStatusNotification sent, wasAttached: 1 isAttached: 1
��Aug 30 18:16:24 Bla-Bla installd[54] <Error>: 0x201000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1cd928e0 [0x3a978100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3a9649f4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1cd73e10 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3a965a44 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1cd897a0 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3a962794 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3a964564 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3a965224 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1cd6e800 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3a961eb4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3a969e84 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3a969eb4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3a967304 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1cd81c40 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1cd6e850 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3a965e54 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3a968bf4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3a969c84 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1cd7f3a0 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
��Aug 30 18:16:26 Bla-Bla installd[54] <Error>: 0x201000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1cd8c720 [0x3a978100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3a9649f4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1cd8ee10 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3a965a44 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1cd8c020 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3a962794 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3a964564 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3a965224 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1cd7f2d0 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3a961eb4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3a969e84 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3a969eb4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3a967304 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1cd90d80 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1cd99040 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3a965e54 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3a968bf4 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3a969c84 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1cd7ea20 [0x3a978100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
��Aug 30 18:16:26 Bla-Bla com.apple.debugserver-199[1186] <Warning>: debugserver-199 for armv7.
��Aug 30 18:16:26 Bla-Bla com.apple.debugserver-199[1186] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
��Aug 30 18:16:26 Bla-Bla com.apple.debugserver-199[1186] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[1177] Builtin profile: debugserver (sandbox)
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla backboardd[26] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla backboardd[26] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla backboardd[26] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla backboardd[26] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.BlaBla.Blast[0xa7df][1189]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.BlaBla.Blast[0xa7df]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 1
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 1 (set level to 0x67a)
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1189] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1189] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/FCCA5177-208D-45C7-A66A-C11372F14E72 (sandbox)
��Aug 30 18:16:27 Bla-Bla com.apple.debugserver-199[1186] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for debugger instructions.
��Aug 30 18:16:28 Bla-Bla locationd[46] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.apple.PassKit failed
��Aug 30 18:16:28 Bla-Bla locationd[46] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.apple.PassKit
��
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of `Simulators` vs `Emulators`. Just a quick start suggestion, have you tried cleaning the project? `Command + Shift + K` I do believe.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127796/running-app-on-iphone4-from-xcode-fails

Comment: Yeap I cleaned the project, also i erased it from the device so that it would build again. After playing around a little, i found out that i have a sigabirt because of the [.... make keyvisable] so now i am error free, yet the problem persist. I read the related question, his problem was code-signing. I tried an another app, just to test if it is code signing but the other one works just fine. So...still have no idea about it..

Comment: @mett hello mett can you tell us which iOS you're using on your iDevice because parse platforms supports iOS 5 and later so make sure you're using iOS above 5.

Comment: @mett, yep, that is very common scenario, but the first rule is: _we never develop application for simulator environment but real device only_. the real device and simulator are quite different, __most of the features are not working properly on simulator__, e.g. file managing, GPS, audio, camera, accelerometer, gyroscope, email, messages... ect, ect, ect... it can cause you very bad time if you want to test only RC/FC version on real device.

Comment: @eptdeveloper, thank you for the respond. I am developing for ios 5 and above, so there is no problem about that.

Comment: @holex, well...this was a good lesson for me. Apart from the features, my problem is something to do with the way I access my initial screen. The real device doesn't accepts it. So no more simulator

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing I noticed, I won't pretend to know a lot about this, but here's what I got:

```
��Aug 30 18:16:24 Bla-Bla installd[54] <Error>: 0x201000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1cd928e0 [0x3a978100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
```

I believe this code says that you're missing of Info.Plist keys, all the red text is the keys that your a missing. Below that is trying to send a bug report to apple.

```
Aug 30 18:16:13 Bla-Bla mobile_house_arrest[1179] <Error>: Max open files: 125
```

This line seems to me that you have too many files open. I wouldn't know how to fix it, but it might give you something to search.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also noticed that but, both of those errors also happened with the other application that I tried for testing. The other one worked just fine. So i still don't know what is causing this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue either. I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: Update*** OK, I was able to solve the black screen issue but not the way i was hoping.I still have problems but not device related. Apparently, it has to do with one of the view controllers(I still don't have errors or warnings though).

Comment: That's really annoying. Don't know what to tell you. You could but the update in your post to bump it.