# iPhone app crashing after launch

Tags: iphone, xcode5, launch

I have a iPhone app that was working till a few days ago. I could run it from Xcode on my phone but today it crashes with the error:

error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/MyAppName.app' -- failed to get the task for process 275

Where xxxx are a set of characters. This is the only warning I get in the Output window.

Closing Xcode and starting again will give different process number on next crash

The app only crashes at random views e.g. the app launches and I can navigate through it up to a certain point, at which it crashes with the error. The next time it may crash on the first views button click.

I have tried a hard reset on my phone but still I get the same problem. I have also deleted the derived data by clicking Options Key -> Product -> Clean build folder... (as I could not find the Developer folder on Lion). I have tried closing Xcode and starting again.

I am using Lion and Xcode 5.0.2.

I am really stuck on this as I have to demo it to a client on Friday and can't figure out what I did wrong?

I have recently added another developer account (working on 2 separate projects, each with its own developer account) and have sent AdHoc demo's through TestFlight to new client.

Could this be what is causing the problem? I have looked in the crashing apps Build Settings -> Code Signing and it appears that i am using the correct account.
This was as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127796/running-app-on-iphone4-from-xcode-fails) thread suggestions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try deleting the app from your phone and run it again from xcode... make sure to capture full exception this time.

Comment: I have tried deleting it as well and running again from Xcode and still no luck. How do I capture full exception? I can't see where to do this. All I get in output window is error as per question.