# Impossible of debugging apps iOS 8.2 Xcode 6.2

Tags: iphone, debugging, crash, xcode6, ios8.2

I update iPhone5-> 8.2 and Xcode-> 6.2 (6C131e) and now do not have a chance to debug any app. Also after several trying phone goes to strange state: screen is black, buttons isn't work, playing music can be manageble with headphones buttons.

App appear in device, opened and work but debug sessions is crashes after 5 sec/begin touching screen. Cable is ok.

Samples of error messages:

**Could not launch**

process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app

**Could not launch**

process launch failed: timed out waiting for app to launch

debugger said something like this:

```
error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5717A964-D3DA-4215-9867-D03B031AB682/AnotherMyPrettyApp.app' -- process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app

error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3D79858C-A854-4AB1-A8D0-650AB6E2D9DF/MyPrettyApp.app' -- process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 186
```

[image]

Attach to debugging session also does not work

[image: Attach to debugging session also does not work]

Now I try to figure out what is wrong on my side or just roll-back to iOS 8.1/ xCode 6 ((

**UPDATE**

Now it start to happen only with one app. This app have some warnings:

[image: warnings while compile]

I think the killed issue is:

```
   /Volumes/work/Projects/Project_ios/PrettyApp_iOS/MyPrettyApp/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/13129560/1067147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Just reassembled project from blank. It is not an answered "why it happen?" but told you "what you can do in this case"

Comment: After half a year I have the same issue. Seems like issue with provision profiles. xCode Version 6.2 (6C131e)

Comment: Also I have strange device issues - impossible to start any program, just select (first time I see it). Hard reset helps. Same issue with 2015 iPad